# Chrome script that refreshes page, notifies me if element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I'm looking to make a chrome script that refreshes multiple pages every minute or so, and if an element on the page exists, I need it to notify me somehow.

I've heard of the Tampermonkey extension for chrome, but I don't know how to continue from here as I'm new to all this.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need a script that runs on all pages (that's `@include *`), `setTimeout` for the timer, standard DOM functions to find the element and `alert` or `GM_notification`. You can find more info by googling for examples and documentation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach might be to use Selenium with the Chrome webdriver instead of trying to use a in browser script.  Its standard library is designed to do exactly what it sounds like you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I won't write whole script for you, but here's a list of things you need to google:

- **Fetching pages's HTML with AJAX** - this will save a lot of bandwidth and CPU. You only need page HTML, not all the images and scripts
- **Regular expressions** - although generally using regular expressions to parse HTML is a BadThing™, for specific case like this it's OK
- **Notifications API** - you can send desktop notifications using JavaScript. Google it.